# Reduce rows that has a repeated values in a column and summarises rest of column in different ways

Tags: pandas

I have a table like this

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['ACOT', '00001', '', '', 1.5, 20, 30],
    ['ACOT', '00002', '', '', 1.7, 20, 33],
    ['ACOT', '00003', '','NA_0001' ,1.4, 20, 40],
    ['PAN', '000090', 'canonical', '', 0.5, 10, 30],
    ['PAN', '000091', '', '', 0.4, 10, 30],
    ['TOM', '000080', 'canonical', '', 0.4, 10, 15],
    ['TOM', '000040', '', '', 1.7, 10, 300]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[
    'Gene_name', 'Transcript_ID', 'canonical', 'mane', 'metrics','start','end'])
```

The output

```
Gene_name   Transcript_ID   canonical   mane    metrics start   end
0   ACOT    00001                               1.5 20  30
1   ACOT    00002                       NA_0001 1.7 20  33
2   ACOT    00003                               1.4 20  40
3   PAN     000090          canonical   NA_00090    0.5 10  30
4   PAN     000091                              0.4 10  30
5   TOM     000080          canonical           0.4 10  15
6   TOM     000040                              1.7 10  300
```

I want this output

```
Gene_name       canonical   mane    metrics
0   ACOT             No       Yes    1.4-1.5
4   PAN              Yes      Yes    0.5-0.4    
5   TOM              Yes       No    1.7-0.4
```

If mane/canonical have a value put yes otherwise put no. Create the range between the highest and the lowest value found in the metrics column.

Comment: Thanks for providing a MWE which works out of the box. To improve this for the next time please use better and more readable code formating (PEP8 style). I edited your code in that direction. And please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . You have to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
f = lambda x: "Yes" if x.any() else "No" # For canonical and mane
df = df.groupby('Gene_name').agg({'canonical': f, 'mane': f, 'metrics': ['min', 'max']})

# Rename columns
df.columns = ["canonical", "mane", "metrics_min", "metrics_max"]
```

Output:

```
            canonical   mane    metrics_min  metrics_max
Gene_name               
ACOT        No          Yes     1.4          1.7
PAN         Yes         Yes     0.4          0.5
TOM         Yes         No      0.4          1.7
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this worked. My question is, if there are more columns that the 4 mentioned and I want to keep them, how can I do this. Merging the results with the previous data frame is the only I can think

Comment: If there are more columns you need to decide what action you want to apply to the column (sum, first, custom function like I did) for each column. Merging will work, but you need to make sure to have the same index on the DataFrame you're trying to merge.

Answer (score 2):

*EDIT*: Beside my solution works I would suggest to accept the answer of @965311532 because it is a very good combination of the "pandas-way" and "pythonic" code. Much less lines and much better to read.

Now my solution:
I have to say your example code doesn't provide the exact output data. Look into `mane` column for example. And the `metrics` column in your desired output doesn't make sense because min-max and max-min are mixed.

My example code here produce this output as sample data:

```
  Gene_name  canonical     mane  metrics
0      ACOT                          1.5
1      ACOT                          1.7
2      ACOT             NA_0001      1.4
3       PAN  canonical               0.5
4       PAN                          0.4
5       TOM  canonical               0.4
6       TOM                          1.7
```

The result after transformation is

```
          canonical mane  metrics
Gene_name
ACOT             No   No  1.4-1.7
PAN             Yes   No  0.4-0.5
TOM             Yes   No  0.4-1.7
```

That is the solution code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['ACOT', '00001', '', '', 1.5, 20, 30],
    ['ACOT', '00002', '', '', 1.7, 20, 33],
    ['ACOT', '00003', '','NA_0001' ,1.4, 20, 40],
    ['PAN', '000090', 'canonical', '', 0.5, 10, 30],
    ['PAN', '000091', '', '', 0.4, 10, 30],
    ['TOM', '000080', 'canonical', '', 0.4, 10, 15],
    ['TOM', '000040', '', '', 1.7, 10, 300]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[
    'Gene_name', 'Transcript_ID', 'canonical', 'mane', 'metrics','start','end'])

# select only the columns we need
df = df.loc[:, ['Gene_name', 'canonical', 'mane', 'metrics']]

# helper function to used in apply()
def my_helper(group):
    # temporary store the result as a dict
    result = {}

    # check for existance of the values
    # it is easy because columnname, value and result column
    # have the same "name"
    for col in ['canonical', 'mane']:
        result[col] = \
            'Yes' if group[col].isin([col]).any() else 'No'


    # I use string format here. Could also be a tuple,
    # list, Series or what every you want.
    result['metrics'] = '{}-{}'.format(group.metrics.min(),
                                       group.metrics.max())

    return pd.Series(result)

desired = df.groupby('Gene_name').apply(my_helper)
```

The important part here is to use [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and then do the calculations and checks in a separate helper function.

#### Some details

About that line

```
def my_helper(group):
    result = {'Gene_name': group.Gene_name.iloc[0]}
```

The `my_helper()` function is called three times for each of your `Gene_name`. The `group` argument is a `DataFrame`. For example in the first call its content looks like this:

```
  Gene_name canonical     mane  metrics
0      ACOT                         1.5
1      ACOT                         1.7
2      ACOT            NA_0001      1.4
```

To collect the results I use a `dict()` here because the keys it are later used as column names for the resulting data frame.

About this line:

```
for col in ['canonical', 'mane']:
    result[col] = \
        'Yes' if group[col].isin([col]).any() else 'No'
```

This maybe looks a bit wired but it is IMHO more pythonic. It could be also written with some more lines like this.

```
if group['canonical'].isin(['canonical']).any():
    result['canonical'] = 'Yes'
else:
    result['canonical'] = 'No'
# and the same for 'mane'
```

The part `.isin(['canonical'])` gives you a list of boolean values. The `.any()` return `True` if there is minimal one `True` in that list and `False` if not.

About that line

```
return pd.Series(result)
```

Here a `Series` object is created out of the `dict`. From the first call of `my_helper()` the series looks like this:

```
Gene_name       ACOT
canonical         No
mane              No
metrics      1.4-1.7
```

It is a list where each item has its own name. The complete code will produce three of such series objects (for each `Gene_name`). The `apply()` does use each series as a row and glue them together to a new data frame.